# Multiple contour plots with different colormaps using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, contour

Using the beautiful pgfplots system, I would like to create a diagram that contains three contour plots for the same pair of axes, with each plot using a different colormap.  The following code works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
    contour/label distance={150pt}
}

\def\f(#1,#2){(((1-x)*(#1)*max(0, (#2) - (1 - (#2)) * y / ((1 - x) * (#1))) + y)^(#2))*((1 - max(0, (#2) - (1 - (#2)) * y / ((1 - x) * (#1))))^(1 - (#2)))}

% w = 1, beta = 0.4
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={red}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,0,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,255);}
}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=0:1,
        y domain=0:1,
        view={0}{90}
        ]
\addplot3[contour gnuplot]
  {\f(1,0.4)};
\end{axis}

% w = 1, beta = 0.5
\pgfplotsset{
  colormap={green}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,255,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,255);}
}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=0:1,
        y domain=0:1,
        view={0}{90}
        ]
\addplot3[contour gnuplot]
  {\f(1,0.5)};
\end{axis}

% w = 1, beta = 0.6
\pgfplotsset{
  colormap={blue}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,255); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,255);}
}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=0:1,
        y domain=0:1,
        view={0}{90}
        ]
\addplot3[contour gnuplot]
  {\f(1,0.6)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: three contour plots]

But if I change some of the parameters, the y-axis gets messed up.  For example, if I change `\addplot3[contour gnuplot]` to `\addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels={0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9}}]` (for all `\addplot3`s) the vertical axes aren't aligned (and the `y domain=0:1` option isn't respected):

[image: three more contour plots]

Any ideas?

Comment: i cannot run your code, but the [restrict y to domain=...] key seems a likely candidate.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the suggestion  --- but adding that key doesn't make any difference.  (To run the code, you need to have gnuplot installed and use the `-shell-escape` option when you run LaTeX or pdfTeX.)

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne I tried your example. Adding `ymin=0` and `ymax=1` should solve your problem.

Comment: @Excelsior Thank you --- I now see the statement in the manual (p. 20) "Note that domain merely controls which samples are taken; it is independent of the displayed axis range (and both can differ significantly)."

Comment: For anyone else doing something similar: adding the keys `hide x axis, hide y axis` to all but the first `axis` helps the appearance of the axis labels.

Comment: But that makes only sense, when you are *sure* that the `axis limits` are the same. Otherwise you might not get the real result you are expecting.

Comment: @StefanPinnow True --- I suggest first starting with them visible, then hiding them when everything is right.  Is there a better way of doing all of this?  Using separate axes doesn't really seem right.  The only reason I did it is that colormaps seem to be axis-specific, not plot-specific.

Comment: I guess you are right that `colormap`s are `axis` and not plot specific.

Comment: Is this question resolved? If not, I might try putting a bounty on it.

Comment: If I could accept a comment as the answer, I would select Excelsior's. The output I wanted is generated by adding the keys `ymin=0` and `ymax=1` to each `\begin{axis}` and then, when the result is correct, adding also `hide x axis` and `hide y axis` to all but the first `\begin{axis}`.  Although this produces the output I want, it doesn't seem like the "right" way to do things---shouldn't there really be only one `axis` environment, not three aligned on top of each other?  However, in `pgfplots`, `colormaps` are `axis` specific, not plot specific, so that multiple `axes` are the only solution.